# Validate data cannot be deleted if referenced by other table

Tags: spring, jpa

I create REST API application using Spring & JPA using Spring Boot.

I've Employee table which referenced by many tables like Family, ID Card, etc (more than 5 tables) and implement soft delete (set mark_for_delete = true)

I want add validation if employee data still referenced by other table, i want throw exception that said "can not delete employee"

What is the best way to do this validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table that stores the number of references that has an Employee.
Anytime you insert or update the Family, ID Card, etc you should update this. To make the validation just verify the number of references is 0.

Doing that way you can add more tables if necessary without change the validation code.